# Function Keys dont work in Openbox

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, openbox, function-keys

**The problem**

Trying to create a desktop environment with `openbox` the `function keys` dont work. Besides in `Unity` they work well.

**What I've tried**

Initially I thought remapping them would solve it, but read about it and seems not to be possible to map the `Function Keys`.

I also tried to check the packages installed related to `Unity` in order to figure out if any would be the responsible for making those keys work, but I can't really find anything usefull, despite there might be.

Thought about creating some kind of shortcuts that would do similar functions but that would be the alst option, as I would really like to be able to use those `function keys`.

**The question**

Is there any way to have them work?

**Info**

Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBY, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a complete solution, because I couldn't test all options right now.

The media keys in most modern Linux desktop environments are handled using setting daemon.

```
XFCE         xfce4-settings: /usr/bin/xfsettingsd
Unity unity-settings-daemon: /usr/bin/unity-settings-daemon
Gnome gnome-settings-daemon: /usr/bin/gnome-settings-daemon
LXDE    #uses openbox, I didn't check
KDE     #uses plasma, I didn't check
```

I tested only `xfsettingsd` in `openbox` session, all media keys work (brightness, switch screen, sleep, print screen) except volume keys.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using the `gnome-settings-daemon` and it works fine. I do not have any volume keys so I can't tell about that.